# click event repeating (jquery 1.9)

Tags: jquery, plupload

```
    $('.image-remove').click(function() {
```

THIS CODE REPEATS TWICE WHEN I CLICK ON .image-remove
I Have no Idea why!

```
$(function() {
var uploader = new plupload.Uploader({
    runtimes : 'html5,flash,html4', // Runtimes in order of priority. If browser does not have HTML5, it will load flash. 
    browse_button : 'agregarArchivo', // Button to select files
    max_file_size : '300mb', 
    dragdrop: true,
    drop_element : 'agregarArchivo',
    url : 'tempupload.php', // PHP file that the images will be sent to server side 
    resize : {width : 400, quality : 60}, // File resize BEFORE it is sent to PHP url
    unique_names:true,
    flash_swf_url : 'js/plupload/plupload.flash.swf', // Required file if flash runtime is used
    filters : [
        {title : "Image files", extensions : "jpg,gif,png"}, // Ensure that only images are loaded
    ],
});

var listaArchivos = new Array();
var cantidadArchivos = 0;
var anchoThumbnail=129; //Incluyendo margenes
var maxFiles=6;
// Initialize Plupload
uploader.init();

uploader.bind('FilesAdded', function(up, files) {

    if( (cantidadArchivos + files.length) > maxFiles)
    {
            // Removing the extra files
            while(up.files.length > maxFiles)
                {
                    if(up.files.length > maxFiles)
                    uploader.removeFile(up.files[maxFiles]);
                }
            alert('Solo puedes subir 6 fotos');
            //uploader.splice(); // reset the queue to zero
        }
    else
        {
            // Go over each file to make sure it is the correct size
            $.each(files, function(i, file) {
                if (file.size > 3*10485759) // If file size is over 30 mb
                    {
                        // Create an image shadow notifying the user of the error
                        $('#upload-dump').append('<div class="image-error"></br>Error: El archivo es demasiado grande (Max 30 MB)</br>' + file.name + '</div>');
                        alert('Error: El archivo es demasiado grande, Max 10 MB');  
                        uploader.splice(i,1);   
                    } 
                else // If the file is under 10mb
                    {
                        cantidadArchivos++;         
                        //Se reduce el tama�o de #agragarArchivo cada vez que una foto se agrega.
                        $('#agregarArchivo').css('width',( (maxFiles-cantidadArchivos) *anchoThumbnail) -4 + 'px');

                        //Si ya se han agregado 4 o m�s fotos, se achica el tama�o de letra y el tama�o de #agregarArchivo
                        if(cantidadArchivos == 4){
                                $('#agregarArchivo').css('font-size','18px');
                                $('#agregarArchivo').html('Click para agregar fotos');
                        }
                        if(cantidadArchivos == 5){
                                $('#agregarArchivo').css('font-size','16px');
                                $('#agregarArchivo').html('Agregar fotos');
                        }
                        if(cantidadArchivos == 6){
                                $('#agregarArchivo').hide();
                        }


                        // Create an image shadow set at 0 percent
                        $('#upload-dump').append('<div id="' + file.id + '" class="image-shadow">0%</div>');

                        //Rename the uploaded file!
                        var regex = /(?:\.([^.]+))?$/;
                        var ext = regex.exec(uploader.files[i].name)[1];
                        uploader.files[i].name = (ext == undefined) ? (i+1) : (i+1) + '.' + ext;


                    }
            });
            up.start();

        }
});

// Maintain progress of the image upload
uploader.bind('UploadProgress', function(up, file) {
    $('#' + file.id).html(file.percent + '%');
});

// Notify user of any errors
uploader.bind('Error', function(up, err) {
    $('#runtime').html('<div> ' + err.message + ':' + err.file.name + '</div>');                                    
}); 

// Do this when each file is uploaded.                                          
uploader.bind('FileUploaded', function(up, file, response) {
    // Change the progress to 100%
    $('#' + file.id).html('100%');
    // Replace the image shadow with the actual thumbnail image
    $('#' + file.id).replaceWith('<div id="' + file.id + '" class="image-picture"><img src="tempthumb/' + jQuery.parseJSON(response.response).result + '" /><div title="Quitar Imagen" class="image-remove"></div> </div> <input type="hidden" id="' + file.id + '" name="' + jQuery.parseJSON(response.response).result +'" value="SI"/> ');
    //Agregar un campo "input" oculto, que se usar� para pasar los nombres de las imagenes al script PHP.
```

//        $('#' + jQuery.parseJSON(response.response).result).insertAfter('');
    });

```
// Do this when all files are uploaded
uploader.bind('UploadComplete', function(up, files) {

    // Allow the user to remove the picture if it's incorrect
    $('.image-remove').click(function() {
        //Quito un archivo del contador.            
         cantidadArchivos--;        

        //Marco el "input" correspondiente a la foto que se elimina, con el valor NO. Este valor se usar� posteriormente en el php que procesa el envio del formulario.
        //Obtengo el id de la foto que se borrar�.
        idborrado=$(this).parent().attr('id');
        //Borro el div donde se encuentra la imagen
        $(this).parent().remove();
        //Ahora que NO hay duplicidad de ID, cambio el valor del input a "NO", que significa que NO se debe considerar esa imagen. No puede ser en otro orden.
        $('#' + idborrado).val('NO');

        //Agrando el tama�o del div #agregarArchivo, y modifico el tama�o de letra de acuerdo a las fotos agregadas.
        if(cantidadArchivos  <= 3){
                $('#agregarArchivo').css('width',( (maxFiles-cantidadArchivos) *anchoThumbnail) -4 + 'px');
                $('#agregarArchivo').css('font-size','30px');
                $('#agregarArchivo').html('Click para agregar fotos');
        }
        if(cantidadArchivos == 4){
                $('#agregarArchivo').css('width',( (maxFiles-cantidadArchivos) *anchoThumbnail) -4 + 'px');
                $('#agregarArchivo').css('font-size','18px');
                $('#agregarArchivo').html('Click para agregar fotos');
        }
        if(cantidadArchivos == 5){
                $('#agregarArchivo').show();
                $('#agregarArchivo').css('width',( (maxFiles-cantidadArchivos) *anchoThumbnail) -4 + 'px');
                $('#agregarArchivo').css('font-size','16px');
                $('#agregarArchivo').html('Agregar fotos');
        }
    });

});
});
/* El script NO borra los thumbnails que se crean, por lo que hay que borrarlos manualmente */
```

Answer (score 6):

I solved it with the following code:

```
$('.image-remove').unbind('click').click(function() {
```

For some reason that I don't understand the click(function() fires twice when you dinamically create a div.

Here is the explanation to the problem:
http://webroxtar.com/2011/10/solution-jquery-click-event-gets-called-twice-fires-twice/

Answer (score 1):

This happens because, when you reload a content that has script within it, that adds a click event, you are actually chainning the click events, twice or more, depends on how many times you load that content. So thats why you should use unbind("click") to make sure to remove previously added binders.

Answer (score 0):

It should be like

```
$('.image-remove').click(function() {
    var uploader = new plupload.Uploader({
    runtimes : 'html5,flash,html4', // Runtimes in order of priority. If browser does not have HTML5, it will load flash. 
    browse_button : 'agregarArchivo', // Button to select files
    max_file_size : '300mb',
```

Dont put the code under below while it comes under an event.

```
$(function(){....})
```

It will run the script while page loads